# Need suggestion on Parser Design Strategy

Tags: java, parsing, dependency-injection, abstract-factory

I need a suggestion on Parser Design Strategy

Consider `type1, type2, type3` are three different csv files with different formats which will be parsed by `Parser1, Parser2, Parser3` respectively.
In future this will evolve to parse info from other sources like dbs.
Also there will be new parsers to come. what is the best way to design the parser? is `factory`/ `abstract` factory a good candidate?
Some benefits and examples would be helpful?

```
Type1 - Parser1    
Type2 - Parser2    
Type3 - Parser3
```

I have put down my code, looking for valuable suggestions.

```
interface Parser<T>{
    public List<T> parse (string s);
}

//where T - data model 

class Parser1CSV implements Parser<Model1>{
    //implement 
    //s-csv file
    public List<Model1> parse (string s){
    }
}

class Parser1DB implements Parser<Model1>{
    //implement 
    //s- connection string
    public List<Model1> parse (string s){
    }
}

class Parser2CSV implements Parser<Model2>{
    //implement 
    //s-csv file
    public List<Model2> parse (string s){
    }
}

//same way other parsers are implemented

interface AbstarctFactory<T>{
    public Parser<T> createParser();
}

class Parser1Factory implements AbstarctFactory<Model1>{
    private String type;
    Parser1Factory(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Parser<Model1> createParser(){
        if(type.equals("CSV"){
            return new Parser1CSV();
        }else if(type.equals("DB"){
            return Parser1DB();
        }else{
            throw UnSupportedOperationException("Not Supported.");
        }
    }
}

//same way other parser factories are implemented

class ParserFactory{
    public static <T> Parser<T> getParser(AbstarctFactory<T> factory){
        factory.createParser();
    }
}

//Usage:
Parser<Model1> parser = ParserFactory.getParser(new Parser1Factory("CSV"));
List<Model1> list = parser.parse(file);
```

Currently, I'm not using DI framework. What will be the benefits and impact when I needed to use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat The decision on what goes where seems to be really complicated. Because I only seldom browse through programmers, I first read their [help page on being on-topic](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Reading about "conceptual questions about software development" and "software architecture and design" and "algorithm and data structure concepts" - with the addition that no point in the _it is not about_ section was hit, I concluded that this seems to be the place. Please tell me where I went wrong, and what place this question belongs to.

Comment: @gnat Additionally, the OP asked this question there and got upvoted (and answered)!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose This question probably *is* on-topic for Programmers, that's not the problem. The problem is that it's just not a very good question no matter where it's on-topic because it's far too broad; I have no idea why the PSE cross-post of this got an upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Design issues have room for personal interpretation/taste, but all in all I like your approach very much, it's common in the industry due to its flexibility & modularity.
**Sometimes** I could do without the hierarchy of Factories, but obviously that varies depending on circumstances.

2) What's the use of your "class ParserFactory"? I don't see that it adds flexibility/decoupling, as opposed to the good old "new Parser1Factory("CSV").createParser()"... but perhaps you had some viable design intent which I've missed.

3) Regarding DI, I could mainly testify to Spring - your code will play very nicely with it. The point of DI is "ok, you know how to create parsers, now how do you pass them on to the business code"? E.g. if you have some 'BankService':

```
// Without DI:
public class BankService {
   private AbstarctFactory factory= new Parser1Factory();
   public void depositFundsFromFile(File file){
      //  use factory
   }
}
// With DI:
public class BankService {
   @Autowired
   private AbstarctFactory factory; // will be injected by the framework
   public void depositFundsFromFile(File file){
      //  use factory
   }
}
```

=> DI makes BankService truly independent of the concrete factory type: BankService doesn't contain the concrete commitment "new Parser1Factory", so it's ready to work with any factory, it even allows several BankService instances to **co-exist** , each with a different factory type... Then you'll give the framework **separate instructions** as to how to create your concrete factori(es) , e.g. "new Parser1Factory("CSV"). With spring such separate instructions come in XML files, or in @Configuration code.

4) Depending on requirements, the DI could also inject a Parser rather than a factory (again, the framework will need separate instructions for Parser creation):

```
public class BankService ... {
   @Autowired
   private Parser parser; // will be injected from the framework
   public void depositFundsFromFile(File file){
      //  use parser
   }
}
```

5) You *could* consider implementing Springs' FactoryBean interface, though you really don't have to: it's a legitimate decision to avoid framework-dependent code.

Comment: Thanks Pelit.  Regarding your question of What's the use of my"class ParserFactory"? After you have pointed me now I see that there is no real benefit from ParserFactory class. I have taken the reference from abstract factory design pattern. Then what is the real use of abstract factory? can you point me some real life cases? It looks like for me Parser1Factory, Parser2factory etc...individual factories are sufficient. Thanks once again for the detailed answer.

Comment: Hi, regarding your specific ParserFactory - the tutorial you saw might have some elaborate intent which I'm missing, but anyway classical AbstractFactory doesn't require it. It just requires is piece of code that finally selects some *concrete* Factory type. Kind of a factory-of-factories (so it's something like 'getFactory'  that returns either newParser1Factory, newParser2Factory etc, with whatever logic you have to decide between them).

Comment: As to AbstractFactory, it's a bit of an English interpretation. AFAIK the original GoF emphasized the specific challenge of creating a *group* of *related* objects. E.g. UI widgets (Button, Checkbox, RadioButton...) that must all be consistent with some theme (all yellowish, or all bluish). The Solution: AbstractFactory with subclasses YellowishFactory, BluishFactory... and then some centralized logic to select the factory (kind of a factory-of-factories) and thus easily switch the theme

Comment: Now your code isn't the classical story because it's only 1 product... but perhaps you could still call it a private case that guarantees all Parsers are the same type. IMHO that's legitimate & works wonderfully. But *sometimes* (just sometimes) when I have just 1 product + simple requirements I might settle for just one simple Factory... and I'm not afraid to refactor in the future if requirements become complex.